# asp.net: Trying to set up a gridview column as an editable drop down

Tags: asp.net

I'm putting together a web page in VS2017 and one of the columns is to be editable, where the user can pick a value from a drop down.  Here's my asp:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="CDRData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"> 
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COLUMN_NM">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label id="ColumnName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.COLUMN_NM") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="COLUMN_IND">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label id="ColumnName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.COLUMN_IND") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ColumnIndList" runat="server" DataTextField='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.COLUMN_IND") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Y" Value="Y" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="N" Value="N" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

When I run this, I get both columns, but no dropdown is visible on the second column.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You need a lot more code for that to work. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: VDWWD: That tutorial did the trick.  Thanks for the info.